# Placing one model inside another in three.js and then moving the model

Tags: three.js

This question is about three.js. I want to place one mesh inside another and then be able to move the mesh that was placed inside the other. The mesh's are loaded using JSONLoader. One is the world and the other is the model itself representing the user. How would I go about doing this? I am able to load both mesh's without difficulty but I am unable to place the user model inside the world model. I then need to perform collision detection to make sure the user does not move through the world walls and objects. It was suggested to use jiblibjs for part of this but that library has not been updated in over 1 year. It was also suggested to use ammo.js for the collision detection. However, that still does not solve the issue of the placing one mesh within another and then moving it. The collision detection with the variety of surfacing in the mesh will have to wait until I am able to do this.

Comment: It would be easier to answer this question if you post some code showing what you have tried

Answer (score 0):

I presume both the user model itself and the world are at the same scale. You can [Object3D](http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/docs/53/#Reference/Core/Object3D)'s add() function to nest objects, but be aware of the hierarchy you export. For example the world object might contain empty objects(with no geometry) and so on. Adding isn't going to be challenging part, collision detection will.

If you're world is somewhat flat (the floor is flat and you need to check collisions against walls you should look up **collision maps**. Basically you'll use an ortographic top view rendered as a monochrome image for example, where one colour will represent areas to check collisions against and the other will represent the non-collidable areas.

If the world has a more complex look you might want to look at [collision meshes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_mesh#Collision): you'll have a simplified/really-low poly duplicate of the world which you will not render, but use to check collisions against, which should be faster rather than checking collisions against each polygon of a complex mesh.

Of course, you also have rigid body libraries like jiglib/ammo/etc. but even with those you should consider using non-rendered low-poly meshes for collisions.

HTH